# How to redirect to a client callback page after a successful authentication via Identityserver4?

Tags: html, angular, identityserver4, openid-connect

I am creating a login server using Identityserver4. I am using ASP.net core 3.1 for functionality, and angular 9 project for serving static files for login/registeration screens. The angular project is being served from within the .netcore project's wwwroot folder.

My flow goes like this

1. javascript client calls OIDC user manager's signInRedirect() method with following configurations[image]
2. This sends a call to my Login method to render the angular's login component. Once the user fills in credentials, a second call is sent to my Login method `return this.http.post('Account/Login', {UserName, Password, ReturnUrl}, {headers, responseType:'text'});`
3. On successfull login, I do a `return Redirect(model.returnUrl);`

   ```
   [HttpGet]
   public IActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
   {
       return Redirect("/login?ReturnUrl=" + WebUtility.UrlEncode(returnUrl));
   }

   [HttpPost]
   public IActionResult Login([FromBody]LoginViewModel model)
   {
       if (ModelState.IsValid)
       {
           var user = _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.UserName).Result;

           var result = _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, false, false).Result;

           if(result.Succeeded)
           {
               return Redirect(model.ReturnUrl);
           }
           return Ok(new Error { ErrorMessage = "Invalid credentials" });
       }

       return Ok(new Error { ErrorMessage = "Some error" });
   }
   ```
4. In my network tab, I can see that the return Url which is a call to IdentityServer's authorization endpoint `/connect/authorize/callback`is successfull. [image]

It has also made a second call to the actual javascript client in point 1 with the authentication successfull. [image]

However, the problem arises here. This request is returning the HTML as string of the JS clients callback.html instead of actually redirecting to that URL(http://localhost:5003/callback.html)[image]

I don't even have any way to access the URL of the returned HTML, otherwise I would have done a window.location.href. How do I capture the URL of the callback page in angular and redirect to it ?

Answer (score 0):

I would need a few more details to remedy this particular situation.  However, I did want to offer my expertise in the form of explaining how this is supposed to work.  I have an NPM library [imng-auth0-oidc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/imng-auth0-oidc) that does this very thing, except that it uses NGRX.

Your callback.html should be a static (non-Angular) HTML page.  You can find a copy here [callback.html](https://github.com/ikemtz/AngularMonoRepo/blob/master/src/libs/imng-auth0-oidc/src/assets/callback.html).  The purpose of this page is to receive the OAUTH2 response and store the token in localStorage, then redirect the response to your Angular application.  Once the application is loaded, you'll now have access to your token that is waiting in localStorage.

-Isaac